# Multi-Device-Hybrid-Apps - has anyone got the indexeddb plugin for android to work

Tags: javascript, indexeddb, multi-device-hybrid-apps

I have been trying to use the indexeddb plugin from msopentech to get my application to work on android 4.2.2 devices.  So far I have had no luck.  My application works fine in the ripple emulator, on any windows 8 tablet and on my nexus 7, but it just doesn't work on android devices running 4.2.2.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

As stated on [Can I use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=indexeddb) you can use IndexedDB, only if you are running Android 4.4 or newer version.

Comment: Thanks Deni, I am assuming that Android 4.4 has native support for indexedDB.  I am trying to use an indexedDB shim library that creates a wrapper around WebSQL.

Comment: if the data that you store is less than 5mb go for local storage, it's supported in all browsers, much simpler than idb or websql

Comment: The application is a semi-disconnected application that will potentially store a lot more that the 5mb limit afforded by local storage.